# window.setTimeout not working in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I am having trouble with this .setTimeout redirect working in safari and ios - does anyone see what i'm missing?

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form#target', function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
          success: function () {
          window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
          }, 2000);
       }
   });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you doing `window.setTimeout()` and not just `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Does you ajax function only have success function? i mean without any url? Also @stybl is correct you can simply use `setTimeout()` rather than `window.setTimeout()`

Comment: @stybl your correct - i removed window. but still having the same issue working on safari